# Splat operator in conjuction with function

Tags: python

I have this program in python which prints the sum of numbers.I have used the splat operator(*). When i print the result i get the result as **None**? 
Can anyone correct this?
I have tried many things like passing multiple arguments but it simply doesn't work.

```
   def addition(*no):
    sum = 0
    for n in no:
        sum=sum+n


print addition(4)
```

Comment: You're not returning anything

Comment: `return` would return something ^^

Comment: When i used return i.e return sum . and i called the function addition(4,5,6) it always return the first argument passed without adding anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your `sum` variable using a `return` statement:

```
def addition(*no):
    sum = 0
    for n in no:
        sum=sum+n
    return sum

print addition(4)
```

You're getting `None` because a function which never uses a `return` returns `None` in Python.

Also note that, if you ever need to write a function which does this in a production environment, there's the `sum` function:

```
def addition(*no):
    return sum(no)
```

Comment: @AnidhSingh `return sum`?? Never does this return `None`

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks. I think my indentation was wrrong.